# Htaccess to reduce false long path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There are long and false paths that work in my website, like 
example.com/contact/img/img/img/img/img/img/img/file.php

Is it possible to make a htaccess which detects those random multiple '/img/' directories and redirect these paths to the index file?

Comment: Would it not make more sense that you fixed the underlying issue instead …?

Comment: Clever advise, i tried this also - i asked the developper of the css framework ...

Comment: Well I can’t guess what the reason might be if you don’t mention it :-) But why would you want to redirect those to the “index file”, what would you gain by that? Would rewriting them to the actual image location (internally) not make more sense?

Comment: I dont know the reason. I dont want to give the name of the free css framework because it works well on the design aspects. And on this problem of paths, it seems out of the developper's control. Actually, it is the SEO guy who detects all of these urls and ask me to redirect them. I am really interested to redirect them to the closer real path, even if it is an image directory ... what syntax do you advise me to use ?